# How to use python loop to through file and execute queries using parameter from text file

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to get a script working that takes each line from a file and use the line as input to run the SQL query. Specifically I'm trying to use a file that has a list of domains and use those domains names to query a postgresql database. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)
import re
import sys
import json

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'


def connect_to_db(domain_name):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'emailAddress' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'));".format(domain_name))
    except:
        print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
    return cursor

def get_unique_emails(cursor, domain_name):
    unique_emails = []
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        matches=re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",str(result))
        for email in matches:
            #print(email)
            if email not in unique_emails:
                if "{}".format(domain_name) in email:
                    unique_emails.append(email)
    return unique_emails

def print_unique_emails(unique_emails):
    print("\033[1;32m[+] Total unique emails found: {}\033[1;m".format(len(unique_emails)))
    for unique_email in sorted(unique_emails):
        print(unique_email)

def write_unique_emails(unique_emails):
    with open('unique_emails.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(unique_emails, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def get_domain_name():
    filepath = 'file.txt'  
    with open(filepath) as fp:  
    for cnt, line in enumerate(fp):
        print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, line))
    return line

if __name__ == '__main__':
    domain_name = get_domain_name()                                             
    cursor = connect_to_db(domain_name)
    unique_emails = get_unique_emails(cursor, domain_name)
    print_unique_emails(unique_emails)
    write_unique_emails(unique_emails)
```

**Code below using sys.argv**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)
import re
import sys
import json

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'

def connect_to_db(domain_name):
    try:
        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'emailAddress' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'));".format(domain_name))
    cursor.execute("SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'serialNumber' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('%{}'));".format(domain_name))
    except:
        print("\n\033[1;31m[!] Unable to connect to the database\n\033[1;m")
    return cursor

def get_unique_emails(cursor, domain_name):
    unique_emails = []
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        matches=re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",str(result))
        for email in matches:
            #print(email)
            if email not in unique_emails:
                if "{}".format(domain_name) in email:
                    unique_emails.append(email)
    return unique_emails

def get_unique_serialNumber(cursor, domains):
    unique_domains = []
    for result in cursor.fetchall():
        matches=re.findall(r"\'(.+?)\'",str(result))
        for serialNumber in matches:
            if serialNumber not in unique_serialNumber:
                if ".{}".format(domain_name) in serialNumber:
                    unique_serialNumber.append(serialNumber)
    return unique_serialNumber

def print_unique_serialNumber(unique_serialNumber):
    for unique_serialNumber in sorted(unique_serialNumber):
        print(unique_serialNumber)

def print_unique_emails(unique_emails):
    print("\033[1;32m[+] Total unique emails found: {}\033[1;m".format(len(unique_emails)))
    for unique_email in sorted(unique_emails):
        print(unique_email)

def write_unique_emails(unique_emails):
    with open('read.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(unique_emails, outfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def get_domain_name():
    if len(sys.argv) <= 1:
        print("\n\033[33mUsage: python emails_from_ct_logs.py <target_domain>\033[1;m\n")
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        return sys.argv[1]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    domain_name = get_domain_name()
    cursor = connect_to_db(domain_name)
    unique_emails = get_unique_emails(cursor, domain_name)
    print_unique_emails(unique_emails)
    write_unique_emails(unique_emails)
    unique_serialNumber = get_unique_serialNumber(cursor, domain_name)
    print_unique_serialNumber(unique_serialNumber)
```

Comment: Just as a quick pointer if this helps: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html
More specifically: "**Warning  Never, never, NEVER use Python string concatenation (+) or string parameters interpolation (%) to pass variables to a SQL query string. Not even at gunpoint.**" (i.e. don't use `.format...` to insert the parameters in your query).

Comment: @Bruno Thanks for your comment. Instead of using '.format', what is the proper way to insert parameters into my SQL query?

Comment: use `%s` placeholders and pass the parameters in the list/tuple as the second argument of `cursor.execute(query, params)` (**NOT cursor.execute(query % params)`**). It's all documented in the link I've put in my comment above.

Comment: @Bruno Thank you again for your comment. Is this what you mean by passing in parameters in the list/tuple as the second argument? cursor.execute("SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower('domain_name'))";

Comment: No. Here, you're hard coding your values within the query string. You should probably do something like this: `cursor.execute("SELECT ci.NAME_VALUE NAME_VALUE FROM certificate_identity ci WHERE ci.NAME_TYPE = 'dNSName' AND reverse(lower(ci.NAME_VALUE)) LIKE reverse(lower(%s))", [ domain_name ])`. Note that a second problem is that you also need to fetch the results somehow once you've executed the query (you're never iterating through the cursor or using any of call to fetch data from it). A third problem is the way `LIKE` works (it seems there's no wildcard in use here).

Comment: @Bruno Thank you again for your help! What exactly do you mean by fetching the results once I've executed the query? Also, what is a better alternative to the term LIKE in my sql query.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Psycopg2](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Psycopg2). Without knowing all the details of your db it's going to be impossible to do a "cut & paste" code dump. The basics are covered [here](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries), which hopefully is enough to get you going. When or if you have more specific questions create a new thread.

Comment: Thanks for your response. If I use sys.args to have the user specify the domain at run-time the query works. It's only not working when I try to read from the .txt file. Do you know an effective method to take the domain name and implement it into the query?

Comment: You are saying if you do something like `domain_name = sys.argv[1]`, it works, but as is, it does not? What does `domain_name` look like in both cases?

Comment: Hi, I added the working code using sys.argv above since it wouldn't let me place it in this window.

Comment: can you add in something like `print("domain_name: {}".format(domain_name))`? Right after `domain_name = get_domain_name()`. Then show the output for what works and what doesn't.

Comment: Hi, thanks for getting back to me. After adding print("domain_name: {}".format(domain_name)) below domain_name = get_domain_name(), I just prints the name of the domains I have in my .txt file. Do you have any other ideas of how to get his working?

Comment: Did you try it for both cases? When you are using `sys.argv` and the text file? Have you tried entering multiple domain_names using `sys.argv` (use quotes on the command line: `something.py "domain1 domain2"`. Without any information on what you are seeing it's pretty hard to help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! When I tried using quotes with sys.argv on the command line and two domains (ie. "google.com apple.com") I get no output from the script. Sys.argv only seems to work with one input parameter.